# axios get request not working inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native, express, jwt

I am using axios get request to check if user logged in or not with jwt, However, when app launched it keeps showing the loading state is it set to true in the first time the app launch then it supposes to make get request and validate the user then set loading state to false and navigate to a specific route. what i am getting is loading state is true all time and request not send to backend server.

here is the function to check if user logged in or not:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        
        const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
            const Token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Token');

            if (Token) {
                axios.get('http://localhost:3000/isUserAuth', {
                    headers: {
                        'x-access-token': Token
                    }
                }).then((res) => {
                 
                    setUser(res.data.user)
                    AsyncStorage.setItem("Token", res.token);
                    setIsLoading(false);

                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                    setIsLoading(false);
                });

            } else {
                setUser(null);
                setIsLoading(false)
            }
        }

        checkLoggedIn();

    }, []);
```

and this is the backend:

```
app.get('/isUserAuth', verifyJWT, (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
  let sqlCheck = `SELECT * FROM users where id =?`;
  CON.query(sqlCheck, req.user, (err, user) => {

    if (user) {
      console.log(user)
      return res.status(400).json({ auth: true, user: user, Token: token })
    }
  })
})
```

Hope someone help me identifying the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your loading state is not changing to `false` that signals to me that it's not a problem with your database call because even if your call is failing the `else` should trigger and still set loading to `false`.

Might consider narrowing down the function complexity and building up from there. Maybe something like the following to make sure your loading state is correctly updating:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    setUser(null);
    setIsLoading(false)
  }

  checkLoggedIn();
}, []);
```

Comment: I have checked that step by step and found it that problem occurs after `}).then((res) => {` which means server either not give response back or the request not sent. from frontend, i have checked fetch instead of axios but same problem

Answer (score 0):

What about setIsLoading to true when the component mounts, then run the async/await based on its value?

```
useEffect(() => {
 setIsLoading(false);
 if (!setIsLoading) {
  try {
   // fetch code 
  } catch(e) {
    //some error handling 
  } finally {
   // something to do whatever the outcome
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: Based on @Ross answer above i have checked the code and actually the problem is with the request its self not with the loading states.

Answer (score 0):

> // I found the solution

the problem is from the backend server where `user`  returns `undefined` and the mistake i made  that only check `if(user)` and didn't set `else` which not give a response back to font-end which indicate that state keep true
so backend code should be like:

```
 CON.query(sqlCheck, req.user, (err, user) => {
    
        if (user) {
         
          return res.status(200).json({ auth: true, user: user, Token: token })
        }else{ return res.status(400).json({ auth: false, user: null })}
      })
```